# javascript: generate random number that are separated by a specific "margin"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, random

I would like to generate `x` random number between `a` and `b`. Each of this `x` random number should not be closer that `y` to the others ones:

If `y = 100` then I shouldn't have 500 and 555 generated but 500 and 601 would be okay.

---

More context:
I would like to generate `x` circles with `d3.js`, that don't touch each other (so `y` would be the radius of the the bigger circle). I could use something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/fabiovalse/bf9c070d0fa6bab79d6a) but I would prefer something without using `force()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a simple b-tree and keep track of the nodes as I go along. This should be very fast and dependable.

```js
let MAX = 100
let MIN = 0
let BUFFER = 10
let MAXCOUNT = 6

function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return {
    val: Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
  }
}

function addLeaves(f, min = MIN - BUFFER, max = MAX + BUFFER, arr = []) {
  if (arr.length >= MAXCOUNT) return arr
  arr.push(f.val)
  f.left = (min + BUFFER < f.val - BUFFER) && addLeaves(randomBetween(min + BUFFER, f.val - BUFFER), min, f.val, arr)
  f.right = (f.val + BUFFER < max - BUFFER) && addLeaves(randomBetween(f.val + BUFFER, max - BUFFER), f.val, max, arr)
  return arr
}


let res = addLeaves(randomBetween(MIN, MAX))
console.log(res)
```

This will give at most `MAXCOUNT` values separated by `BUFFER`. It's possible it will return fewer than `MAXCOUNT` if there is no room in the range given a large buffer. Because of the nature of the b-tree, it will fill out gaps as necessary.

EDIT:

Since we don't actually use the tree structure(it might be useful in other circumstances thought), this can be rewritten to use the raw numbers. This changes it to a single function call to make reuse easier:

```js
function getRandom(min, max, buffer, maxcount) {
  let randomBetween = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

  function addLeaves(f, min, max, arr = []) {
    if (arr.length < maxcount) {
      arr.push(f);
        if(min + buffer < f - buffer) addLeaves(randomBetween(min + buffer, f - buffer), min, f, arr);
        if(f + buffer < max - buffer) addLeaves(randomBetween(f + buffer, max - buffer), f, max, arr);
    }
    return arr
  }
  return addLeaves(randomBetween(min, max), min - buffer, max + buffer)
}
// now you can call with just: min, max, buffer, maxcount
let res = getRandom(0, 100, 10, 6)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hey, how do you enable the "run code snippet" thing?

Comment: Hey @JimBaldwin - if you add the code as a 'snippet' (there's a button when you're posting the answer) it will let it run in place.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Please don't do that for your accepted answer: it will freeze the browser.

Comment: @Mark_M I'm avoiding answering this question because it seems to be a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The example in the answer will certainly return in finite time.  Also, what's an XY problem?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you're probably right. I thought it was interesting on its own merits and (at least to me) wasn't obvious how to solve.

Comment: @JimBaldwin No, it will not: imagine the first value is 30 and the second value is 70. The `while` loop will run forever. Just try your code and you'll see.

Comment: XY:  thanks for the link. I've definitely seen this pattern.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks.  I introduced that error when I was trying to clean up the post.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this @Mark_M, I would like to call  `addLeaves(randomBetween(MIN, MAX))` many times with different  
 `BUFFER` and `MAXCOUNT`, so I would like to extend `addLeaves()` to something like this `addLeaves(randomBetween(MIN, MAX), BUFFER,MAXCOUNT )`. Accordingly, I have change `function addLeaves(f, BUFFER, MAXCOUNT, min = MIN - BUFFER, max = MAX + BUFFER, arr = []) { but I get and error `Identifier 'MAX' has already been declared`. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Hey @Enora - you should be able to do this. You just need to make sure you pass `BUFFER` and `MAXCOUNT` in everywhere you call addLeaves. Looking at this again, I've noticed that since we don't actually use the tree structure it's just overhead. It can be rewritten as a single function that works with the raw numbers. I'll post an edit in a minute.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: The first few numbers will always be in descending order until there is no more space because of the buffer. So, for example, this snippet will never generate an array where the first two numbers are 10 and 20 in that order. In fact, when the first number happens to be 10, the next will be *guaranteed* to be 0. One would expect a bit more randomness...

Comment: That's a good observation @trincot. I got the impression from the question (drawing circles on a canvas) that the order wasn't significant. But the distribution is definitely not equal. For example drawing 4 numbers from 20 with a buffer of 4 will give ~ 0.065 probability of both 0 and 1 rather than the 0.05 probability of an fair distribution. I'm not sure, however, whether this is a consequence of the problem of this particular solution. It becomes much more fair as the buffer shrinks in relation to range.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be to loop on Math.random() until you get an answer that isn't in the no-fly zone.  The downside is some unnecessary calls to Math.random, but if the no-fly space is small compared to the range it wouldn't be significant.

UPDATE:  avoid history of results.  fun.

```
let history = [];
function myRand(range, margin) {
    while(true) {
        let result = Math.trunc(Math.random() * range);
        if (history.every(last => {
            return Math.abs(result - last) > margin;
        })) {
            history.push(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    console.log(myRand(100, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have troubles seeing how I can extend your code to generate something like 25 random number. Let's say that those 50 number should be between  0 and 1000 with a margin of 20.

Comment: Ah, I see, you want to avoid a series of numbers, not just the last one.

Comment: As @GerardoFurtado mentioned this doesn't work especially well. If there is no room between numbers given a margin it will just loop forever. Also it's not clear when the third argument as in the function call `myRand(100, 50, 10)`

Comment: Yes, I pointed that out in my answer.   It really depends on whether the number space is crowded.  If the space is crowded you would need something more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, though it feels a little less random to me.  It doesn't run the risk of infinite loops in the case of a narrow space.

```
function randomWithMargin(start, stop, count, margin) {
    let spacing = Math.trunc((stop - start) / count);
    let left = start;
    let right = start + spacing;

    let results = [];
    while (count--) {
        let r = left + Math.trunc(Math.random() * (right - left));
        results.push(r);
        left = r + margin;    // ensure next number is at least margin from last
        right += spacing;    
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(randomWithMargin(10, 110, 10, 7));
```

Comment: This seems to give numbers outside the range when called with a large margin. For example: `randomWithMargin(10, 110, 10, 70)` returns `[ 10, 74, 141, 92, 114, 149, 125, 183, 178, 222 ]`